# Spring post json

Tags: java, json, spring, post

I try to build my first api. I got problem when i want to register new user. The problem is when i want to send request from postman. I using also SwaggerUI, so when i use Post Request to my end point /registration in SwaggerUI by textfields always i got http status 201 so its works good. Problem is when i want to make Mock to this controller or when i want to send new user in postman request but not always. I show you in example

If i use postman -> post: localhost:8080/registration -> Raw -> JSON

```
{
  "email": "testtest@gmail.com",
  "id": 0,
  "password": "Test1234567  ",
  "username": "testtest"
}
```

Then i got message

```
{
    "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "timestamp": "01-03-2021 11:44:26",
    "message": "Value cannot be empty!",
    "debugMessage": null,
    "subErrors": null
}
```

So its should be good because i used catch exception. But Value isnt empty, so whats happend?I dont know.
But when i go to x-www-form-urlencoded and there i put keys: email, username and password then, user is created!

Another, when im put this same info to Swagger then also my user is created.

Below i add my code from controller and test.

```
@Test
void shouldCreateNewUser() throws Exception {
    UserRegistrationDto user = new UserRegistrationDto( null,"seba12345", "lelelele1908@gmail.com", passwordEncoder.encode("Respeck123"));

    mockMvc.perform(post("/registration")
            .header("header1", "1")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}



@PostMapping("/registration")
public ResponseEntity<UserRegistrationDto> registerUser(UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    userService.save(userRegistrationDto);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(userRegistrationDto, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `@RequestBody` in your controller method to tell Spring that you want the content of the request body:

```
@PostMapping("/registration")
public void post(@RequestBody MyDTO dto) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) That was pretty simple, im spent a lot of time to looking for problem from other side.